# Prolog - combine2 how to prevent adding an empty list at the end

Tags: list, prolog

I'm learning Prolog via learnprolognow. Currently I'm on chapter4 and am stuck on [the second exercise](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse17).

"Now write a 3-place predicate combine2 which takes three lists as arguments and combines the elements of the first two lists into the third as follows:

```
?-  combine2([a,b,c],[1,2,3],X).    
X  =  [[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]] "
```

My implementation of this is:

```
combine2([],[],[]).
combine2([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[[H1,H2],R]):-
   combine2(T1,T2,R).
```

The result of the query above tho is:

```
 X = [[a, 1], [[b, 2], [[c, 3], []]]] ;
```

I do not know how to re-write it, so in the last step the program is not adding an empty list. I am open to suggestions/hints/solutions.

Thank you and have a nice sunday!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your implementation: `[[H1,H2],R]` is a list with two elements the element [H1,H2] and the element R. What  you need to write is `[[H1,H2]|R]` which represents a list of head element [H1,H2] and the rest of the list R which will be recursively instantiated. Note that the line `[[H1,H2],R]`  does not only cause an empty list in the end but it also nests your list because you are not getting `X = [[a, 1], [b, 2], [c, 3], []] ;` (which just has an empty list) but nested lists like: X = `[[a, 1], [[b, 2], [[c, 3], []]]] ;`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that makes totally sense.

Comment: I just thought that in the Head there only can be 1 element. So that is not true? Or the "one" element can be a variable as well?

Comment: The Head is the first element of the list and is a variable that is being instantiated currently in the list e.g the clause combine2([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[[H1,H2],R]):-... instantiates the head element [H1,H2] (which is a variable) with the known heads H1,H2 of the other lists. The head is one element but this one element could be like in your case a list of the form [H1,H2], or in other example could be an element of the form (H1,H2) or H1-H2 and goes on....

Answer (score 2):

You have to change only a char: `|` instead of `,` in `[[H1,H2],R]`: i mean, `[[H1,H2]|R]` instead of `[[H1,H2],R]`.

If you use a comma, you create a new list with two elements: (a) the list `[H1,H2]` and (b) the list `R`

If you use a pipe, you insert (in first position) the list `[H1, H2]`, followed by elements in `R`.